# How to make this scollable screen with images in phaser js

Tags: phaser-framework

my problem is here https://youtu.be/Qh07gBzZIMI
With tabs and scrolls like this same as it 
[image]

my code is here
https://www.codepile.net/pile/20xOgJGg

Comment: checkout this phaser plugin(s)https://phaser.discourse.group/t/phaser-3-rexui-plugins/384  it has oll the features that you mentioned, but has to be configured.

Comment: here the link to the documentation https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/ui-overview/